# Scatter Chart in Excel

Tags: excel, graph, charts, coordinates, scatter-plot

I have data in excel:

[image]

I want to have a scatter chart where I see the data as dots.

[image]

The issues is that, for example, for Product A, it will show me two dots, one at 3 and the other one at 5.

I would like to see it as one dot with coordinates (3,5) as my x-axis should be the "Price" (Column D in Chart Data sheet) and the y-axis the "Suitability" (Column E in Chart Data sheet).

If I do not select the product column in the chart data source, then I get the results (see sheet Chart 2) but then I do not have the information that which product a dot signifies.

[image]

Could you please provide a solution that shows the dots (with a label showing against each dot as to what product it signifies).

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the chart as in your second example
2. Select the data points in the chart and right-click on them
3. From the popup menu, select "Add Data Labels -> Add Data Labels"

[image]

4. Select the Data Labels and right-click on them
5. From the popup menu, select Format Data Labels

[image]

6. From the Label Options, uncheck "Y Value" and "Show Leader Lines" and check "Value From Cells"
7. Once you have check "Value From Cells", a dialog box appears, use it to select column A as the source of data labels

[image]

The final result:

[image]